# (NodeJs) Command line arguments to PhantomJs child process along with script args

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, spawn

I have the following code that works:

```
var Path = require('path')
var Phantomjs = require('phantomjs2')
var phantomjsPath = Phantomjs.path
var childArgs = [
      Path.join(__dirname, 'phantomjs-worker.js'),
      'http://...some login url...',
      3000, //login timeout
      'http://...some address to render as image...',
      5000, //address timeout
      '...output image file path...',
      1000, //page width
      1000, //page height
      1234 //some id
    ]            
var child = Proc.spawn(phantomjsPath, childArgs, { cwd: process.cwd() })
```

Inside phantom-worker.js:

```
var argsOffset = 0;
var login = system.args[argsOffset + 1];
var logintimeout = system.args[argsOffset + 2];
var address = system.args[argsOffset + 3];
var addresstimeout = system.args[argsOffset + 4];
var output = system.args[argsOffset + 5];
var pageWidth = parseInt(system.args[argsOffset + 6]);
var pageHeight = parseInt(system.args[argsOffset + 7]);
var pageId = system.args[argsOffset + 8];
...
```

I need to be able to pass in

```
--ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=tlsv1
```

as well.

I tried adding these as the first 2 arguments but it doesn't work. It starts looking for the output image file path for some reason and obviously fails.

Is there any way to pass in these command line arguments along with the script and its child arguments?

Comment: Shouldn't argsOffset = 2 in that case?

Comment: Tried that as well. It still counts the script as index 0 and the following items from 1.

Comment: Putting phantomjs params as first elements of childArgs (before Path.join) seems working. Maybe your case is more complicated, sorry.

Comment: I'll try that again. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is working in my local test environment now ... then it must be something to do with environment, paths or permissions, as the real environment is based on Docker and DCOS. I'll see if I can solve that and comment here.

Comment: Did you managed to find the error?

Comment: Yes, actually got it working simply with the arguments as the first few arguments, and no  need to change the offset. I'll post the answer shortly. The issue was related to phantom crashing due to low memory and the parent app looking for the rendered file which obviously wasn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works as expected. The error was not in this part of the code. Rather, the phantom process was exiting due to memory issues causing the rendered image file to be not created.

```
var Path = require('path')
var Phantomjs = require('phantomjs2')
var phantomjsPath = Phantomjs.path
var childArgs = [
      '--ignore-ssl-errors=true',
      '--ssl-protocol=any',
      '--web-security=false',
      Path.join(__dirname, 'phantomjs-worker.js'),
      'http://...some login url...',
      3000, //login timeout
      'http://...some address to render as image...',
      5000, //address timeout
      '...output image file path...',
      1000, //page width
      1000, //page height
      1234 //some id
    ]            
var child = Proc.spawn(phantomjsPath, childArgs, { cwd: process.cwd() })
```

Worker:

```
var webpage = require('webpage'),
    system = require('system');

var login = system.args[1];
var logintimeout = system.args[2];
var address = system.args[3];
var addresstimeout = system.args[4];
var output = system.args[5];
var pageWidth = parseInt(system.args[6]);
var pageHeight = parseInt(system.args[7]);
var pageId = system.args[8];
```